# How do I color line segments between specific points in a d3 line plot?

Tags: d3.js, colors

I have a simple line plot of time vs. A data value that is dynamically updated. That is, I periodically add a new data value and once a "max value" is reached I start removing a data value from the data set when a new value is added. The line plot is "animated" and this is working so that a new point appears on the right end of the line while the oldest point disappears from the left. Based on certain attributes of the new data (the value being plotted and some other associated values) I need to alter the appearance of the line segment connecting the latest data value and a certain number of prior plotted data values.

For example, say that the data values are a simple "object" consisting of { Time, DataValueToPlot, FlagValue }. As I said I am currently plotting each data object's "DataValueToPlot" against an X axis of Time. Let's say that the last 3 values plotted are (1PM,10), (2PM,20) and (3PM,30) (although the real times are not uniform). We have plotted the 10, 20 and 30. Now a new value of (4PM,15) arrives and the 15 value is added to the line plot but this new value has an associated FlagValue that indicates that the prior three line segments are to be drawn, say, in red with a large stroke-width. How can this be accomplished?

To be clear, I am not asking to draw a colored line segment whenever any data value exceeds or falls below a specified value but rather, I need to be able to change the appearance of selected line segments.

======================= RESPONSE to @jshanley
Thanks for your sample code.  I see that it would allow me to associate the appropriate color with a "line" (segment) but I can't get this to work.  I had originally used the common pattern of binding the data array with an svg path where I used a line function to described how to draw the data points such as:

```
lineFcn = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return(d.Time); })
        .y(function(d) { return(d.DataValueToPlot); })
        .interpolate("linear");
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width",500)
                                    .attr("height",500);
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFcn(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke","black")
                            .attr("stroke-width",1)
                            .attr("fill","none");
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't apply your suggestion to it because you are associating a stroke attribute with each "line" (segment) but in the above code we don't have any such elements.  I tried to rewrite the code so that I don't use an svg path with the svg line() helper function, but instead just create a collection of separate "line segments".  That means that in your "enter" block of code we extend the selection.enter().append('line') to add the X1,Y1 and X2,Y2 coordinates but that is the problem.  I can't locate any method that lets me define these values.

I tried to extend your suggestion to something like:

```
selection.enter().append('line')
        .attr("x1",function(d,i) { return(d[i-1].Time); })
        .attr("y1",function(d,i) { return(d[i-1].DataValueToPlot)); })
        .attr("x2",function(d,i) { return(d].Time); })
        .attr("y2",function(d,i) { return(d].DataValueToPlot)); })
```

but the reference to "d[i-1]" triggers an error.

1) Is there some way for an accessor function to refer to the "prior" data value?
2) Can you expand your prior code sample to show me how to actually draw each line segment where you are setting a stroke attribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the standard Enter, Update, Exit pattern [described here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218), you could insert some branching logic into the update section, and switch colors or other styles based on whether the FlagValue has appeared.

```
function update(data) {

  // reset the flag
  var flagged = false;

  var selection = svg.selectAll('line')
    .data(data);

  // ENTER
  selection.enter().append('line')
    // adding the attribute is superfluous
    //  but it gives us a callback in which
    //  we can set `flagged` to `true`
    .attr('data-flagged', function(d) {
       if (d.FlagValue === true) {
         flagged = true;
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
    });

  // ENTER + UPDATE
  // set the stroke based on whether `flagged` is true
  selection.attr('stroke', function(d) {
    if (flagged) {
      // could also add more conditional
      //  logic here to change only certain lines
      //  for example
      // if (d.time < someTimeVar) { return 'blue'; }
      return 'red';
    } else {
      return 'green';
    }
  });

  // EXIT
  selection.exit().remove();

}
```

Comment: I have just learned that I cannot enter a detailed reply as a Comment and I have had to Edit my original post to reply to your suggestions.  Can you tell me how I am supposed to provide a detailed reply to a response?  But also, please see my reply. Thanks.